# Converting SQL to Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.1

I'm converting some project from pure PHP to Laravel 5.1, and I have a problem with converting this query:

```
\DB::select( "SELECT TABLE_NAME as nombre, FORMAT(TABLE_ROWS, 0) as cantidad 
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = '".env('DB_DATABASE')."' " );
```

to Eloquent ORM. Can you help me?

Comment: I believe answer is: Is there any way to retrieve db schema with Eloquent? Not just: how to write this query with sqlbuilder?

Comment: Take a look to [Schema](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema). Especially `Schema::hasTable()` and `Schema::getColumnListing()`

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to write

```
\DB::table('tables')
    ->where('table_type', 'BASE TABLE')
    ->where('table_schema', env('DB_DATABASE'))
    ->select(
        'TABLE_NAME as nombre',
        \DB::raw('FORMAT(TABLE_ROWS, 0) as cantidad')
    )
    ->get();
```